# retrieving multiple values from checkbox and hidden field

Tags: php

my code works as expected but a little issue occurred, i try retrieving values from checkboxes with same name and hidden fields with the same name, it works but one of the hidden field keeps on returning the first value even if the checkbox was not selected.
here is my code

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res1)){
?> 
    <tr><td class='bold'><?php echo $sn;?><input type="hidden" name="snum[]" value="<?php echo $sn; ?>" /></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['subLocationName']; ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="location[]" value="<?php echo $row['dllink_id']; ?>"/></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="available[]" value="<?php echo $row['subLocationName']; ?>"/></td>
    <input type="hidden" name="locationID[]" value="<?php echo $row['locationName']; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="sublocation[]" value="<?php echo $row['subLocationName']; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="device[]" value="<?php echo $row['deviceName']; ?>"/>
    <td></td><td></td></tr>
<?php
        $sn++;
    }
```

the values are from my database.
the retrieving code is this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_btn'])){

        $serial_num = $_POST['snum'];
        $locationDeviceLink = $_POST['location'];
        $linkAvailable =$_POST['available'];
        $location = $_POST['locationID'];
        $subLocation = $_POST['sublocation'];
        $device = $_POST['device']; 
        $measure_date = date("Y-m-d");
        $sn = count($linkAvailable);
            for ($i=0; $i<$sn; $i++ ){
                if(!empty($linkAvailable[$i])){
                    echo "serial number:".$serial_num[$i]."  location:".$locationDeviceLink[$i]."  available:".$linkAvailable[$i]."  Location:".$location[$i]."  subLocation:".$subLocation[$i]."  Device:".$device[$i]."  Date:".$measure_date."<br/>";


                }

            }



    }
```

the problem is the subLocation value, it keeps returning the first value then the second as it appears even if the associated checkbox is not checked and another checkbox is checked, please can anyone help me out, cant't think of anything more.
thanks in advance
joseph O

Answer (score 0):

Rather then testing for `!empty` try using php's function `isset`.

```
for ($i=0; $i<$sn; $i++ ){
  if(isset($linkAvailable[$i])) {
    echo "serial number:".$serial_num[$i]."  location:".$locationDeviceLink[$i]."  available:".$linkAvailable[$i]."  Location:".$location[$i]."  subLocation:".$subLocation[$i]."  Device:".$device[$i]."  Date:".$measure_date."<br/>";
  }
}
```

Comment: every value is retrieved correctly except the subLocation, i have used isset still the same result, is it that the code is not well link or what? not that isset does not work, it is OK. the issue is that the subLocation value always return the same value from the top even if i checked the last row only

Comment: As far as I can see the code you have posted appears to be correct.  Isset is the standard accepted way to check if a checkbox is checked. As you have already shown it is not the only way, however, since we are still getting the wrong results for the code I am left to believe that there may be an issue somewhere else in the code.  At this point if you wish to post more of the form code and the print code we can try to look further for some type of incorrect assignment elsewhere.

Comment: thanks for your time if any issue i will be back here and if i am able to solve the issue i will be back too to post the correct code